# How do I select with linq an attribute from an xml tag on the same level?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

In the below xml I'm trying to select the FieldName UserName, and from the same level in a different property obtain the "Value"

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong in the linq query

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Objects>
  <Object>
    <Property Name="Value" Type="System.String">DeathStar</Property>
    <Property Name="FieldName" Type="System.String">Server</Property>
   </Object>
  <Object>
    <Property Name="Value" Type="System.String">Luke</Property>
    <Property Name="FieldName" Type="System.String">Username</Property>      
  </Object> 
 </Objects>

        var usernameValue =
            from v in
                from e in xd.Descendants().Elements()
                let p = e.Parent
                where
                    e.HasAttributes
                    && e.Name.LocalName.Equals("Property")
                    && e.Attribute("Name").Value.Equals("FieldName")
                    && e.Value.Equals("UserName")
                select p
            where
               v.HasAttributes
               && v.Name.LocalName.Equals("Property")
               && v.Attribute("Name").Value.Equals("Value")
            select v.Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to base the query on `Object` elements from which you can check `FieldName` and return the corresponding `Value` :

```
var usernameValue =
        from o in xd.Descendants("Object")
        where 
            o.Elements("Property")
             .Where(p => (string)p.Attribute("Name") == "FieldName" && (string)p == "Username")
             .Any()
        select 
            o.Elements("Property")
             .Where(p => (string)p.Attribute("Name") == "Value")
             .Select(p => (string)p)
             .FirstOrDefault();
```

Also notice that XML is case-sensitive, so `Username`, as in your XML, won't be matched by `UserName`, as in your LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

This will work, you have to filter collection twice, first at Object level and next at Property value.

```
var resultnode = doc.Descendants("Object")
    .Where(d=> d.Descendants("Property").Any(c=>c.Attribute("Name").Value == "FieldName") && d.Descendants("Property").Any(c=>c.Value == "Username"))
    .Descendants("Property")
    .Where(p=>p.Attribute("Name").Value == "Value")
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Now value can be accessed using.

```
if(resultnode != null)
{
    resultnode.Value; // value  
}
```

Working [`Code`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MjbwvV)

Comment: Thanks I ended up going with this resharper was complaining about replacing with a single call to FirstOrDefault, so I removed the Where clause and moved the where lambda into the .FirstOrDefault. I think it looks more clean as it is not sure why resharper complained.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad problem resolved it helped in finding best solution. I would suggest write the answer with the solution found and mark this question answered, it might help other people.